# How to display text and plotly chart with gradio in the same output box

Tags: python, plotly, chatgpt-api, gradio, gradio-chatinterface

I have a code which is a chatgpt agent answering questions about our database (text to SQL basically). The code works perfectly on its own. However I need to demo it to my management so I need to have some kind of front end to it.

As front end programming it is not my area, I thought I will go with something easy. I thought gradio will do the job, so it is my first gradio app.
It works nicely however I run into a problem. The chatbot I created is able to display the text replies however the user can ask for visualization of the results. When asked to visualize the chatbot agent uses plotly.

My problem is that the output text box I am using with gradio cannot display the visualization, only the text.
So my question is that, does gradio have an output item which can display text and visualization as well?

Here is my gradio code:

```
demo=gr.Interface(fn=generate_reply, inputs='text', outputs='text')
demo.launch()
```

Comment: No, there is no such abstract component for handling inputs/outputs of mixed types. You mention "_the visualization_", and "_when asked to visualize the chatbot agent uses plotly_", but what is it exactly that you call _visualization_ ? Is it the python code that creates the plotly figure ? is it the figure object itself ? It would also help to know what does generate_reply look like.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Well, it can be both, right? I mean in the prompt I can definitely ask the LLM to provide me only the plotly code or the object itself. 
At this stage I am running it locally in my jupyter notebook environment and in this environment (as it is able to handle python code) I see the created chart/diagram  (so the object) itself. This is what I would like to see in the gradio output box as well.
I am thinking maybe if I ask the model to output the prompt as HTML code in string, than I could display that in gradios' HTML box, right?

Comment: The thing is, the function generate_reply needs to distinguish what type of output the LLM generates so that it can then pass that output to the proper output component. A plotly figure should be mapped to a [`gradio.Plot()`](https://www.gradio.app/docs/plot) output, so you would need to set `outputs=['text', 'plot']`. Now, even if your function is supposed to return either A (text) or B (plot), it will still need one output for each type and thus always have to return both A and B, which implies to set some default (empty value or placeholder) for the unused output.

Comment: But yes asking the LLM to output everything in full HTML and put that into one gradio.HTML() output might be a good idea, the result would depend more on the LLM itself, but you would have the benefit of having a "mixed" component.

Answer (score -2):

To display text and a Plotly chart in the same Gradio output box, follow these steps:

1. **Import Gradio and Plotly:**

   ```py
   import gradio as gr
   import plotly.express as px
   ```
2. **Create Plotly Chart:**

   ```py
   chart_data = px.data.iris()
   fig = px.scatter(chart_data, x='sepal_width', y='sepal_length', color='species')
   ```
3. **Combine Text and Chart:**

   ```py
   output_text = "This is a Plotly Chart:"
   output_chart = gr.Image(fig.to_image(format="png"))
   ```
4. **Define Gradio Interface:**

   ```py
   iface = gr.Interface(fn=lambda: (output_text, output_chart), live=True)
   ```
5. **Launch Gradio Interface:**

   ```py
   iface.launch()
   ```

   This code sets up a Gradio interface with both text and the Plotly chart displayed in the same output box for a seamless user experience.

Comment: I did ask chatgpt myself as well and this is the same answer I got. Which is not an answer to my question.